# ajuda com o codigo abaixo

Tags: swift

Boa tarde, pessoal!

Estou tentando fazer um app e não consigo fazer a programação para que não passe para o campo seguinte com o campo vazio.
Do jeito que o código esta se deixar em branco e apertar em calcular o sistema fecha.

Acredito que por conta da conversão, pois, se deixo de maneira normal o teclado por ser português não aceita a virgula, então tive que fazer a conversão.

Se algum puder me ajudar, agradeço!

Abaixo o código, completo.

```swift
import UIKit

class MediasViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var Litros: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var MKhini: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Mkhfin: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var MresultadoKh: UITextField!

    @IBAction func btnMedia(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let LitrosGeral = Double(self.Litros.text!)!
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()

        func convertToDouble (_ string: String) -> Double {
            formatter.numberStyle = .none
            return formatter.number(from: string)!.doubleValue
        }

        formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
        let Mkhini = convertToDouble(MKhini.text!)

        let Mkhfina = convertToDouble(Mkhfin.text!)
        var resultadoMediakh = (Mkhini - Mkhfina) * 17.8 * LitrosGeral

        if resultadoMediakh / 79.8 < 0 {
            (resultadoMediakh = 0)
        } else {
            resultadoMediakh = (resultadoMediakh / 79.8) / 3
        }
        MresultadoKh.text = String (format: "%.1f", resultadoMediakh)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let alerta = UIAlertController (title: "Alerta", message: "teste", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let confirmar = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alerta.addAction(confirmar)

        present(alerta, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sim o erro ocorre na conversão pois não consegue converter um campo vazio para um numero e voce esta forçando isso utilizando o !, o que você pode fazer é trocar

```swift
   let LitrosGeral = Double(self.Litros.text!)!
```

por

```swift
   let LitrosGeral = Double(self.Litros.text!) ?? 0
```

Assim toda vez que o campo estiver vazio ele vai considerar como 0

Agora para que não passe para o campo seguinte com o campo atual vazio você deverá implementar a função

```swift
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {...}
```

do protocolo
`UITextFieldDelegate`,
esta função irá ser chamada cada vez que for digitado um caractere em um textfield que esteja setado o delegate com sua ViewController, por tanto, não esqueça de setar desta maneira:

```swift
   Litros.delegate = self
```

A seguir o código com a validação de cada textfield para habilitar o próximo:

```swift
import UIKit

class MediasViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var Litros: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var MKhini: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Mkhfin: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var MresultadoKh: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var calculateButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func btnMedia(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let LitrosGeral = Double(self.Litros.text!) ?? 0
        let Mkhini = Double(MKhini.text!) ?? 0
        let Mkhfina = Double(Mkhfin.text!) ?? 0

        var resultadoMediakh = (Mkhini - Mkhfina) * 17.8 * LitrosGeral

        if resultadoMediakh / 79.8 < 0 {
            (resultadoMediakh = 0)
        } else {
            resultadoMediakh = (resultadoMediakh / 79.8) / 3
        }
        MresultadoKh.text = String (format: "%.1f", resultadoMediakh)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Litros.delegate = self
        MKhini.delegate = self
        Mkhfin.delegate = self
        MresultadoKh.delegate = self

        MKhini.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        Mkhfin.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        MresultadoKh.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        calculateButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }

    // função para liberar o próximo TextField conforme ir completando
    func checkTextField() {
        let litrosCompleted = Litros.text!.count >= 1
        let iniCompleted = MKhini.text!.count >= 1
        let finCompleted = Mkhfin.text!.count >= 1

        if (litrosCompleted && !iniCompleted && !finCompleted) {
            MKhini.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        } else if (litrosCompleted && iniCompleted && !finCompleted) {
            Mkhfin.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        } else if (litrosCompleted && iniCompleted && finCompleted) {
            calculateButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }
    }
}

extension MediasViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        checkTextField()
        return true
    }
}
```

Lembrando que este é apenas um exemplo simples de como pode ser feito e que este código não trata caso o usuário volte ao primeiro campo e o apague, porém caso o usuário faça isso o app ira rodar normalmente porque todo campo vazio esta sendo tratado com o valor 0, Um próximo passo seria voce tratar cada vez que seja apagado todo campo o aplicativo o completar com 0.

Certifique-se também que o Content Type do teclado seja do tipo numérico para que não se possa digitar letras no TextField